# Changed stored procedure to use real tables instead of temp tables now it takes much longer to run

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I'm working with SQL Server. There is a very long stored procedure that was using many temp tables. We were having issues with the log file filling up in tempdb so we decided to change all temp tables to real tables so it uses the bigger log file.

After I changed all of the tables from temp to real, the stored procedure is taking much longer to run (like 30-40 mins longer). Original is about 30 mins.

The tables are identical including the indices. I thought speed wise it would be close to the same.

The data is identical (from the old procedure with temp tables to the new procedure with real tables).

Indexes are there on the new tables...

Can someone tell me why using real tables the process takes longer? Should it take roughly the same time to run?

Comment: When you say changed from "temp tables" to "real tables", do you mean you've created actual new physical tables instead of your temporary ones? Because that'll most likely create a hole lot more I/O as well. Take a look at STATISTICS I/O and STATISTICS TIME for your two versions

Comment: yes, I've created actual new physical tables.

Comment: Most likely you have I/O issues now. I/O from the tables, I/O from logging. I/O from index maintenance etc. And if you're "lucky" your server is on some slow network discs. As suggested, check statistics to see if that's the case, also check execution plans, verify server performance counters etc against your two versions of the query to figure out where the bottlenecks are

Comment: I see I see. I'll take a look. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Use truncate if you are deleting data from real tables before inserting

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the execution path to make sure you have all indexes as your old table? I wouldn't be surprised if the execution path has changed quite a bit.